# printing turtle-graphics canvas with canvasvg.saveall()

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, canvasvg

I tried the following which I found on this site:

```
from turtle import *
import canvasvg

def saveImg():
    name = input("What would you like to name it? ")
    nameSav = name + ".svg"
    ts = getscreen().getcanvas()
    canvasvg.saveall(nameSav, ts)

penup()
goto(-60,-225)
pendown()
left(90)
hideturtle()
speed(0)
forward(20)

saveImg()
```

This is the error message I got:

```
File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    saveImg()
  File "test.py", line 8, in saveImg
    saveall(nameSav, ts)
NameError: name 'saveall' is not defined
```

I know that `canvasvg` includes a definition for `saveall()`, so I don't see why it cannot find this function.

Please help and try to be simple in your answers as I just started coding ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `canvasvg` includes `saveall` then you must do `canvasvg.saveall()`. If `saveall` were inside `turtle`, then you would have it because you did `from turtle import *`.

Your other option is changing `import canvasvg` to `from canvasvg import *` but [I don't recommend it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad).

---

**UPDATE:**

I tried to run your script and I noticed that, actually, `canvasvg` contains two different submodules: `canvasvg.canvasvg` and `canvasvg.setup`. I don't know why. However, you can just replace:

```
import canvasvg
```

With:

```
from canvasvg import canvasvg
```

And then you can call `canvasvg.saveall()`.

However, I discovered that [there is a bug](https://github.com/WojciechMula/canvas2svg/issues/2) in the last Python 3 version of canvasvg. Thus, you should either wait for canvasvg developers to fix it, or you can use the Python 2 version of canvasvg.

If you want to switch to Python 2, you should only change `input` to `raw_input`. I tested and it seems to work flawlessly.

Comment: Sorry, I posted a work in progress of the code from when I tried to make it work. I actually used canvasvg.saveall() at the beginning without success. Do you have any other recommendations? 
Thanks

Comment: What is the real error then? The error posted in the question clearly shows that `saveall()` was used instead of `canvasvg.saveall()` :)

Comment: I did run your script to see the error and I updated the answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're a real help. I'll try and see if my complete program runs in Python 2.

Comment: I tried both, using python 3 and 2 on after the other with the alterations you proposed but I still get the following error message:
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\canvasvg.py", line 147
    warn("Items of type '%s' are not supported." % itemtype)
UserWarning: Items of type 'image' are not supported.